# PCA output different each run

Tags: pca, matlab

I am trying to analyse my data that contains many NaNs values by learning a PCA from Matlab: https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html
There is an example of using ALS Algorithm input argument for dealing with NaNs dataset. Then, I tried to make a biplot out of it, however, it seems the biplot is different everytime.

```
load hald
    [coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained] = pca(ingredients);
    y = ingredients; % adding NaNs into the dataset
    rng('default'); % for reproducibility
    ix = random('unif',0,1,size(y))<0.30; 
    y(ix) = NaN; % NaNs are now included in the dataset
    [coeff1,score1,latent,tsquared,explained,mu1] = pca(y,'algorithm','als');
figure();
    biplot(coeff1(:,1:2),'scores',score1(:,1:2),'varlabels',{'A','B','C','D'})
```

Biplot 1 (First run)
[image: Biplot 1]
Biplot 2 (second run)
[image: Biplot 2]
The biplot would not change if I did not include the NaNs or ALS algorithm argument which the script becomes like this below:

```
load hald
    [coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained] = pca(ingredients);
figure();
    biplot(coeff(:,1:2),'scores',score(:,1:2),'varlabels',{'A','B','C','D'})
```

Biplot 3 without using ALS argument and no NaNs.
[image: Biplot 3]

Is it because of the input arguments which somehow changed the biplot? or did I miss something?

Thank you very much.
Regards.

Comment: You have to be very careful doing imputation for PCA and factor analysis. The signs of the components are arbitrary and small changes to the data can reverse the signs.

Comment: Does the PCA imputation affect significantly towards the results and eventually the biplot?

Comment: Well, if the signs of the components are different on different imputations and then you combine them, you are going to get a mess.

Comment: How to deal with missing data largely depends on why there is missingness in the first place and what you intend to do with the results. Could you edit your question to clarify?